# Monorepo: How to consume a package from another project?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to create my first monorepo in Go. The project structure looks as follows:
[image]

As you can see on the picture, the `monoplay` folder is the root.
The `pb` folder contains the generated `gRPC code` that I would like to consume in the `srv_boo/main.go` and `srv_foo/main.go` files.

The question is, how to consume the generated `gRPC code` from folder `pb` in the `srv_boo/main.go` and `srv_foo/main.go` files?
Is the folder structure correct?

Would like also to deploy the services individually.

Is maybe https://bazel.build/ the solution?

Comment: Every module should have a `go.mod` file including the module that includes your protoc-generated packages.

Comment: I find this gnarly but my solution is to always include `go_package` in the proto files and then use `go_opt=module=${MODULE}` and `go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE}` as a way to localize the package placement in a local directory. I think there are alternatives too.

Comment: On a related note, are you aware of [`go.work`](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md#proposal-the-file)?

Comment: the question is also, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the entire repository as one go module will help with this, i.e only one go.mod file in the "Monoplay" root folder.
Then the services can reference the generated go files using "github.com/*/monoplay/pb/*" imports.
This will also centralize dependency management for all the entire repository, since there is only one go.mod file, if that is something you want.

Other alternatives:
Using "go mod edit":
https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-edit
Or, as DazWilkin suggests, use "go_package" in proto files together with "go-grpc_opt" and "go_opt".

I use the single module approach and recommend it.

If the repository will contain a lot of code and building everything (including container images) is cumbersome and takes to long then look into bazel.